# SendInput without a binding keyword

Tags: vmware, autohotkey

I am trying to send input to VMWare Player when I switch to it. This is so that do not have press <kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd> and make the VMWare grab my input. The following is the script I came up with, but it does not do anything. What is it that missed?

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class VMPlayerFrame
{
    SendInput, {Ctrl down}g{Ctrl up}
}                                                                               return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use #IfWinActive to change hotkeys or hotstrings, but not to create scripts.

You need to detect the window change, and act on that.

```
#SingleInstance
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam )
{
    If (wParam = 4 or wParam = 32772) ; Without VMware Player running: wParam = 4, with VMware Player running: wParam = 32772
    {        
        IfWinActive ahk_class VMPlayerFrame
        {
            SendInput, {Ctrl down}g{Ctrl up}
        }
    }
}
Return

; Hotkey {Win}+g launches Chrome
#g::Run "C:\Users\%A_Username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

; Hotkeys {Ctrl}+Nr gives you fractures
^2::
    Send, ½
    TrayTip, For 2 Squared,press Ctrl + Shift 2,1,1
Return

^3::
    Send, ¾
    TrayTip, For 3 Cubed,press Ctrl + Shift 3,1,1
Return

^4::Send, ¼

; HotKeys {Shift}+{Ctrl}+Nr gives you the power
+^0::Send, °
+^1::Send, ¹
+^2::Send, ² ; Shift Control 2@
+^3::Send, ³ ; Shift Control 3#

; Hotstrings mvge, mvgd or mvgf will give you my salutations in various languages.
:*:mvge::Regards,{Enter}{Enter}Robert Ilbrink
:*:mvgd::Mit freundlichen Grüßen,{Enter}{Enter}Robert Ilbrink
:*:mvgf::Salutions,{Enter}{Enter}Robert Ilbrink
```

Comment: I am new to hook in AHK. Is is possible to combine this code with my existing hotstrings and hotkeys? I have tried, but was without success.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to know if you can also have hotstrings and hotkeys in the same script? The answer is YES. As long as you place the hotstrings UNDER the first or second `Return`. At startup all AutoHotKey lines are executed until the first `Return`. By placing all other hotstrings/hotkeys under the first section, you make sure that the first section can be executed on start-up. Does this help?

Comment: Is this 'hook' considered a hotstring or a hotkey? What I mean is can I combine THIS solution with my existing .ahk file which contains hostrings and hotkeys.

Comment: I reduced the switching code, by removing some obsolete lines and added some examples of hotKEYS and hotSTRINGS. A HotKEY is a SINGLE (mostly) key press often combined with modifiers like {Shift}, {Ctrl}, {Win} or {Alt}. A HotSTRING is a string that you type (visible or not) which is executed when it matches. HotSTRINGS are often used for "expanding" text, correcting common mistakes, or even writing whole standard replies (potentially even with inserted variables) in an e-mail.

Comment: P.s. I have thrown the If (wParam = 4) back into the script because without it there are too many window messages (e.g. switching a tab) that would trigger the Ctrl+g.

Comment: Thanks, there must be something I need to change in order to combine them together. In my case, **32772** worked instead of **4** for the wParam value.

Comment: You are right, when VMware Player is active, the wParam switch signal is changed from 4 to 32772. Once the VMware Player is closed, this is switched back to 4.